# How to override default Content-type

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, minimal-apis

I have a minimal-API ( Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" ) app that has a GET endpoint that I would like to return an image/png.

The endpoint is:

```
app.MapGet("/text2img/{inputText}", (string inputText) => {
  var fileBytes = new ByteArrayContent(text2img(inputText).ToByteArray());
  var mimeType="image/png"; 
  var fileBytesArray = fileBytes.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
  return Results.File(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FileContentResult(fileBytesArray, mimeType).FileContents);
});
```

And it returns the correct bytes for a png-image, but the content-type is octet-stream:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 24975
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Fri, 22 Oct 2021 16:29:49 GMT
Server: Kestrel
```

How do I return the correct Content-type?

Comment: I haven't work with .net6 but I do it in .net5 with `Response.Headers["Content-type"] = "something";` I hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Results.File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.results.file?view=aspnetcore-6.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_Results_File_System_Byte___System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Nullable_System_DateTimeOffset__Microsoft_Net_Http_Headers_EntityTagHeaderValue_) (at least in the latest version) has parameter for `contentType` you can just pass byte array and content type to it:

```
app.MapGet("/img", () =>
{
    var mimeType = "image/png";
    var bytes = ...
    return Results.File(bytes, contentType: mimeType);
});
```

Comment: "at least in the latest version" +1